# Take a break to make a snake!

Tags: code-golf

Our classic snake has developed an inbalance of [growth hormones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_hormone). To make matters worse, his tail is frozen in place! Given directional input as specified in `Figure 1`, write a program to determine where he will grow.

[image: wasd]

*Figure 1.* Directional input.

## Program specifications

- Read the **input** character by character on `STDIN`.
- After reading a character, **output** the snake to `STDOUT`. Please include a blank line in between each time you print a snake.
- The snake consists of `<>v^` and a head. The head of the snake may be any round character of your choosing, such as `o`, `0`, `O`, or `☺`.
- Any combination of `wasd` is valid for input.
- Your program should not assume the input is within a certain length.
- The snake can pile on top of itself, overwriting `<>v^`. See examples for snake growing mechanics.
- Trailing whitespace is okay, but your snake must look correct.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score is the number of characters in your program. Lowest score wins!

## Example snakes:

**Input:** `ddddssaassdddddww`

**Output:**

```
>>>>v
    v
  v<<  ☺
  v    ^
  >>>>>^
```

---

**Input:** `dddsssaaawww`

**Output:**

```
☺>>v
^  v
^  v
^<<<
```

---

**Input:** `dddsssdddddasddddwww`

**Output:**

```
>>>v
   v       ☺
   v       ^
   >>>>v<  ^
       >>>>^
```

---

**Input:** `dddwwdddssssaaaaaaaaawww`

**Output:**

```
      >>>v
☺     ^  v
^  >>>^  v
^        v
^<<<<<<<<<
```

---

**Input:** `ddddssssaawwddddd`

**Output:**

```
>>>>v
    v
  >>>>>☺
  ^ v
  ^<<
```

---

**Input:** `dddddssaawwwwddddd`

**Output:**

```
   >>>>>☺
   ^
>>>^>v
   ^ v
   ^<<
```

---

**Input:**

```
ddddaaaasssssdddddddddddwwwwwaaaasssssdddddddddddwwwwwwwwwwsssssaaaasssssdddddddwwwwwddddssaaaasssddddaaaassssssssssdddwwwwwwwddddswaaaassssddaasssaaaaaaaaaawwwwddddssssaaaaaaaaaaawwwwddddsssssssssaaaa
```

**Output:**

```
                  v
                  v
                  v
                  v
                  v
v<<<<  v<<<<  v<<<<  >>>>v
v      v   ^  v   ^  ^   v
v      v   ^  v   ^  v<<<<
v      v   ^  v   ^  v
v      v   ^  v   ^  v
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>v<<<<
                     v
                     v
                     v  v<<<<
                     v  v   ^
                     v  v
       >>>>v  >>>>v  v  v
       ^   v  ^   v  v  v<<
       ^   v  ^   v  v  v
       ^   v  ^   v  v  v
       ^<<<v<<<<<<<<<<<<<
           v
           v
           v
           v
       O<<<<
```

Comment: Very nice. But... WTH is a "code gofl"?

Comment: I'd get rid of the bonus as it is way too easy to create your own snake and input string.

Comment: @JanDvorak rotfl my bad.

Comment: @BetaDecay done.

Comment: Also, does the snake start in a random position on the top line?

Comment: @BetaDecay the snake starts at the top left corner, but if the input causes the snake to grow farther up or to the left then the whole snake shifts so it can still be printed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @chilemagic is leading whitespace OK?

Comment: @JanDvorak Your snake should be flush to the left like the examples.

Comment: Why isn't there a path to the top of the d in the code golf example though?

Comment: @BetaDecay it's hidden  behind the downwards path

Comment: @JanDvorak Where the snake start off originally then? It's supposed to start in the top left corner, so why isn't there a path near the top left corner? Does the plane automatically scale to fit the path?

Comment: @BetaDecay the plane scales. In the code golf example it started at the top left of the c, but since the d is taller it moves down.

Comment: I guess an `@` is a valid head? It doesn't save me code, but I think it looks nice.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah `@` is valid!

Comment: 1. If my language of choice cannot read a single character at a time, can I assume that there's one character per line? 2. Does the plane have a maximum width/height?

Comment: @Dennis I'd rather say it's fair to assume there's one line of input only

Comment: As for #2, anything above 80 characters will probably confuse the console. It shouldn't confuse you, though.

Comment: are extraneous leading lines OK?

Comment: @JanDvorak a few leading lines (<5) would be fine.

Comment: @Dennis you can assume there is one character per line. There is no maximum width/height, but you can assume you won't overflow 32 bit integers and stuff like that.

Comment: I'm confused. I went with the examples and printed the entire snake in its final state. But reading the bullet points, it sounds like I have to print the snake after every character. Which one is it? Everyone seems to assume printing the final snake is fine.

Comment: @IngoBürk I wanted the snake to be printed after every character and have the program accept one character at a time. I don't think I made that clear enough in the question so I'm willing to accept either way. You can just print the final snake.

Comment: @chilemagic Thanks! If both are acceptable you should probably clarify this in the question.

Comment: @chilemagic I think it's time to start marking the winner, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @IngoBürk I love that you included the gifs in your answer! Since this is code-golf, I believe the winner is Jan Dvorak but I haven't tested his solution yet. I will mark it soon! The question is almost a month old.

Comment: @chilemagic Yes, I didn't win despite my animation efforts. But that's okay. ;)

Comment: In order to make it happen on early Sinclair machines (ZX80 and ZX81) could my snake consist of `<>VA` instead please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ruby, 207 characters

```
b=[];x=y=0;gets.chars{|c|b[y]||=[];b[y][x]={?\n=>->{?0},?w=>->{y>0?y-=1:b=[[]]+b;?^},?a=>->{x>0?x-=1:b.map!{|r|[' ']+r};b[y][1]=?<},?s=>->{y+=1;?v},?d=>->{x+=1;?>}}[c][]};puts b.map{|r|r.map{|c|c||' '}.join}
```

Ungolfed:

```
b=[]  #board
x=y=0 #position
gets.each_char{|c|
  b[y] ||= []
  b[y][x] = {
    "\n" => lambda{0},
    "w"  => lambda{if y>0 then y-=1 else b=[[]]+b; "^"},
    "a"  => lambda{if x>0 then x-=1 else b.map!{|r|[' ']+r}; b[y][1]="<"},
    "s"  => lambda{y+=1; "v"},
    "d"  => lambda{x+=1; ">"}
  }[c].call}
puts b.map{|r|r.map{|c|c||' '}.join}
```

(the lambda for `a` writes back because the row the assignment above writes to is no longer on the board)

Answer (score 11):

## ECMAScript 6 Javascript (399 <s>401</s> <s>431</s>)

Has to be run in a browser supporting ECMAScript 6 due to the arrow functions.

Here are fiddles which have been altered to run in any (common) browser by not using arrow functions. They also print to a `textarea` instead:

- [Normal](http://jsfiddle.net/924aw5o7/1/)
- [Animated](http://jsfiddle.net/924aw5o7/2/)

### Golfed Version

```
i=prompt(),v=[],c=0,x=[0],y=[0],s='unshift',k='slice',t='sort',h=[0,-1,0,1,0]
while(c<i.length){m='wasd'.indexOf(i[c++]);v[s]('^<v>'[m]);x[s](x[0]+h[m]);y[s](y[0]+h[m+1])}f=(a,b)=>a-b
q=x[k]()[t](f)[0],e=x[k]()[t]((a,b)=>b-a)[0],w=y[k]()[t](f)[0],o=[]
while((i=y.pop())!=null){i-=w;j=x.pop()-q;t=(o[i]||Array(e+1-q).join(" ")).split("");t.splice(j,1,v.pop()||"@");o[i]=t.join("")}alert(o.join("\n"))
```

### Animated GIF:

One of the OP's examples:

[image]

The example from [Stretch Maniac](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37095/26765):

[image]

### Ungolfed

Here is a (slightly) ungolfed version from sometime before I started *really* golfing it down:

```
var input = prompt(),
    values = [],
    c = 0,
    x = [0],
    y = [0],
    s = 'unshift';
while (c < input.length) {
    var mapped = 'wasd'.indexOf(input[c++]);
    values[s]('^<v>'[mapped]);
    x[s](x[0]+[0, -1, 0, 1][mapped]);
    y[s](y[0]+[-1, 0, 1, 0][mapped]);
}

var minX = x.slice().sort(function (a,b){return a-b})[0];
var maxX = x.slice().sort(function (a,b){return b-a})[0];
var minY = y.slice().sort(function (a,b){return a-b})[0];

var output = [];
while((i=y.pop())!=null) {
    i-=minY;
    j=x.pop()-minX;
    t=(output[i]||Array(maxX+1-minX).join(" ")).split("");
    t.splice(j,1,values.pop()||"@");
    output[i]=t.join("");    
}

console.log(output.join("\n"));
```

Comment: The gifs are very cool. Are they made automatically, by a script you've written?

Comment: Thanks! With the power of Google I just looked up how to make a gift from a screen recording in Ubuntu. It just uses a screen recorder and `convert`. Pretty easy :)

Comment: (gif, not gift)

Answer (score 8):

## sed, 71

```
s/w/\^\x1B[D\x1B[A/g
s/a/<\x1B[2D/g
s/s/v\x1B[B\x1B[D/g
s/d/>/g
s/$/@/
```

## Golfscript, <s>165</s> 126

```
' '*"\33[":e{e'D'}:-{[e'C'+'<'--]]}:a{[-+'>']]}:d{[e'B'+'^'-e'A']]}:w{[e'A'+'v'-e'B']]}:s{][\[}:+7{;}*''\~[e'H'e'J']\'@'e'20H'
```

Same approach as my previous answer, but correctly positioning the cursor before and afterwards. I'm pretty proud of the approach to cursor positioning -- basically, it first runs the snake in reverse, without printing out characters.

Comment: Can you add an example call? `echo "dddddssaawwwwddddd" | sed -e 's/w/\^\x1B[D\x1B[A/g' -e 's/a/<\x1B[2D/g' -e 's/s/v\x1B[S\x1B[D/g' -e 's/d/>/g' -e 's/$/@/'` doesn't give the correct output for me.

Comment: Your prompt after executing is probably overwriting part of the snake. Paste the snake directly into stdin instead of piping, or add a few `\n`s after the `@` so your prompt goes elsewhere.

Comment: This might fail if the snake goes up or left of the board.

Comment: @tomsmeding Yeah, I might expand it to deal with that. Language aside, though, I really think ANSI control sequences are the way to go for shorter code.

Answer (score 3):

## Java - 646

Might as well be the first one!

I bet you all can beat this.

un(sort of)golfed

```
import java.util.*;
public class Snake{
    public static void main(String[]a) {
        int x,y,minX,minY,maxX,maxY;
        x=y=minX=maxX=minY=maxY=0;
        List<Integer>xs,ys=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        xs=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Character>p=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int b=0;b<a[0].length();b++){
            int newX=x,newY=y;
            switch(a[0].charAt(b)){
            case'a':newX--;p.add('<');break;
            case's':newY++;p.add('v');break;
            case'd':newX++;p.add('>');break;
            case'w':newY--;p.add('^');break;
            }
            xs.add(x);ys.add(y);
            x=newX;y=newY;
            if(x<minX){minX=x;}
            if(x>maxX){maxX=x;}
            if(y<minY){minY=y;}
            if(y>maxY){maxY=y;}
        }
        char[][]c=new char[maxY-minY+1][maxX-minX+1];
        for(int i=0;i<xs.size();i++)c[ys.get(i)-minY][xs.get(i)-minX]=p.get(i);
        c[y-minY][x-minX]='@';
        for(char[]k:c){for(char l:k){System.out.print(l);}System.out.println();}
    }
}
```

Smaller -

```
import java.util.*;class S{public static void main(String[]a){int x,y,o,z,s,u;x=y=o=s=z=u=0;List<Integer>j,t=new ArrayList<Integer>();j=new ArrayList<Integer>();List<Character>p=new ArrayList<Character>();for(int b=0;b<a[0].length();b++){int e=x,r=y;switch(a[0].charAt(b)){case'a':e--;p.add('<');break;case's':r++;p.add('v');break;case'd':e++;p.add('>');break;case'w':r--;p.add('^');break;}j.add(x);t.add(y);x=e;y=r;if(x<o)o=x;if(x>s)s=x;if(y<z)z=y;if(y>u)u=y;}char[][]c=new char[u-z+1][s-o+1];for(int i=0;i<j.size();i++)c[t.get(i)-z][j.get(i)-o]=p.get(i);c[y-z][x-o]='@';for(char[]k:c){for(char l:k){System.out.print(l);}System.out.println();}}}
```

input - dddsssdddwwwwaaaaaaaassssssssssddddddddddddddddd

```
v<<<<<<<<         
v >>>v  ^         
v    v  ^         
v    v  ^         
v    >>>^         
v                 
v                 
v                 
v                 
v                 
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>@
```

input - dddsssdddddasddddwww

```
>>>v        
   v       @
   v       ^
   >>>>v<  ^
       >>>>^
```

my personal favorite - dwdwdwddaasassdddddwdwdwddsdswawaasassdddddddwdwdwddsdswawaasassddddwwwwwwwssssssdsdddwwwwddaassddaassddddsssdddwdwdwddaasasassddddwwwwssssssssasasaaawdwwdwddwwdddddddwdwdwddsdswawaasassddddddddddwwdwwwwaasssassdsdddddddwdwdwwwwasasssssssssssdwwwwwwwddd

```
                    v                                          
                    v                                          
                    v                                          
                    v   v<<                                    
   v<<   v<<     v<<v   v                                      
  v<    v< ^<   v< ^v   v<<                        v<<     v<  
 >v    >v   ^  >v   >v  v                          v ^    v<^  
>^>>>>>^>>>>>>>^>>>>^>>>>>>>v    v<v               v ^    v ^  
                            v   v< v       v<<    v< ^    v ^  
                            v  v<  v      v< ^<   v >^    v>^  
                            >>>v   v     >v   ^   >v^     v>>>@
                               >>>>>>>>>>^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>v^   
                                  ^v                      v^   
                                >>^v                      v^   
                               >^  v                      v^   
                               ^  v<                      v^   
                              >^ v<                       v^   
                              ^<<<                        >^
```

Comment: [619 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZJNb6MwEIb/CjfwYlB6xQxptaeVessRsZIDbmpCMPJHsIn47ayhG6WtVF/m9TzvjO2RW3qliRhY3zbnZeGXQUgdtD6ZGs279BepO6pUcLgN5tjxOlCaah@ugjfBhfI@OmjJ@1NZUXTjvQ4sdljgCStsMMdHsOBAgIIJDOwww5K8cqXzP71mJyaLFno2Bi9SUvclHyGsf0QfLX6/U0lr7TPDN@eDeO@bkBE55rTksKvSjvUn/e7TBlxh9i4z6MbAEgmOcKClt9S@@kVHxzhGhL9FHCCkoXclCRlS2jRRmIeIzP@R8kjG8R1dP6FmrXqg4hMa16pHw78rajdtEdGbcIhYYMSBJAJsLvY2E0SBLZRXikzg8snffyLzeuGyKqt6G8O2M8kUP1WlSoQP2wjq0iVTVdpEVBA@h4Tnbar4xPwoUF3q9MR0xNFqae/aO4cPvY5ia7KddM5qdLtvgy47o4NTml1SYXQ6@N@go67Y7bssDPy7vrOu90fO87wsS9M0SqlmXXQL4zj@Aw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## C# 607

```
namespace System{using B=Text.StringBuilder;class P{static void Main(){var f=new Collections.Generic.List<B>(){new B("O")};int w=1,r=0,c=0;for(Action R=()=>f[r].Append(' ',w-f[r].Length+1);1>0;){var key=Console.ReadKey(1>0).KeyChar;if(key=='w'){f[r][c]='^';if(--r<0)f.Insert(r=0,new B());R();f[r][c]='O';}if(key=='a'){f[r][c]='<';if(--c<0){foreach(var s in f)s.Insert(c=0,' ');w++;}R();f[r][c]='O';}if(key=='s'){f[r][c]='v';if(++r>f.Count-1)f.Add(new B());R();f[r][c]='O';}if(key=='d'){f[r][c]='>';if(++c>w++)foreach(var s in f)s.Append(' ');R();f[r][c]='O';}Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",f)+"\n");}}}}
```

"Ungolfed" with whitespace (this will not be kept in sync with the golfed version):

```
namespace System
{
    using B = Text.StringBuilder;
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var f = new Collections.Generic.List<B>() { new B("O") };
            int w = 1, r = 0, c = 0;
            Action R = () => f[r].Append(' ', w - f[r].Length + 1);
            while (true)
            {
                char key = Console.ReadKey(1>0).KeyChar;
                if (key == 'w')
                {
                    f[r][c] = '^';
                    if (--r < 0) { f.Insert(0, new B()); r = 0; }
                    R();
                    f[r][c] = 'O';
                }
                if (key == 'a')
                {
                    f[r][c] = '<';
                    if (--c < 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var s in f)
                            s.Insert(0, ' ');
                        w++;
                        c = 0;
                    }
                    R();
                    f[r][c] = 'O';
                }
                if (key == 's')
                {
                    f[r][c] = 'v';
                    if (++r > f.Count - 1) f.Add(new B());
                    R();
                    f[r][c] = 'O';
                }
                if (key == 'd')
                {
                    f[r][c] = '>';
                    if (++c > w++)
                    {
                        foreach (var s in f)
                            s.Append(' ');
                    }
                    R();
                    f[r][c] = 'O';
                }

                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", f) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: 259 Bytes

```
x=y=0
b,p,r={},(0,-1,0,1),range
while 1:
 d='wasd'.index(input());b[(x,y)]='^<v>'[d];x+=p[d];y-=p[~d];b[(x,y)]='☺';l,m=([k[i]for k in b]for i in(0,1))
 for j in r(min(m),max(m)+1):print(''.join(b[(i,j)]if(i,j)in b else' 'for i in r(min(l),max(l)+1)))
 print()
```

I decided to store the snake in a dict, with coordinates for the keys. Then find and iterate over the output range, substituting blank spaces.

```
x = y = 0
board = {}
while 1:
    d = 'wasd'.index(input())
    board[(x, y)] = '^<v>'[d] # body
    x += (0, -1, 0, 1)[d]
    y -= list(reversed((0, -1, 0, 1)))[d]
    board[(x,y)] = '☺' # head

    xs, ys= ([coord[dim] for coord in board] for dim in(0, 1))
    for j in range(min(ys), max(ys)+1):
        print(''.join(board[(i,j)] if (i,j) in board else ' '
                      for i in range(min(xs), max(xs)+1)))
    print()
```

PS.
My first Golf :)
Let me know if my answer is inappropriate

Comment: Using `O` instead of `☺` saves you 2 bytes. `☺` is a red herring.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ `☺` wasn't actually counted as 3 bytes.

Comment: @MartinEnder [It must be](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#☺), the default encoding is UTF-8. I had a feeling it wasn't counted. I have a feeling it was accidental and must be immediately fixed by Gilly.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Well technically, the answerer is free to use any encoding supported by their interpreter (and I'm pretty sure some ASCII-compatible code page contains that character) but that's beside the point. I'm saying the byte count is already the same as that of using `O`, so I wouldn't worry about it. It's clear from the code that it would still work for any other character but using `☺` lets you conveniently run the test cases from the challenge without changes.

Comment: @MartinEnder Python uses UTF-8, proved by its ability to support unicode strings. To enable this functionality, the first or second line must be `#coding=utf-8`. Note that `#coding=utf-16` does not work. Hence `☺` must be counted as 3.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ No part of this is true. Python 3 uses whatever encoding is defined by the system as the source code encoding, as well as for the default of `str.encode` and `bytes.decode`. The magic comment `#coding=utf-8` is ignored in Python 3.

Comment: Yes I naively just used the string length rather than the actual size, ignoring encoding. If you'd really like @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I can modify the answer to use a 0. By the way, what is the "standard" way to measure your submission length? So I know for next time.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2.7 - 274 bytes

```
x,y,m,d,r=0,0,{},(0,-1,0,1),range
for c in raw_input():b='wasd'.index(c);m[(x,y)]='^<v>'[b];x+=d[b];y-=d[~b];m[(x,y)]='@';l,n=([k[h] for k in m] for h in (0, 1))
for j in range(min(n),max(n)+1):print(''.join(m[(i,j)] if (i,j) in m else ' 'for i in range(min(l),max(l)+1)))
```

### Ungolfed version

```
x,y,matrix,delta = 0,0,{},(0, -1, 0, 1)    
for c in raw_input('Command: '):
    d = 'wasd'.index(c)
    matrix[(x, y)] = '^<v>'[d]
    x += delta[d]
    y -= list(reversed(delta))[d]
    matrix[(x, y)] = '@'    
xs, ys = ([xy[i] for xy in matrix] for i in (0, 1))
for j in range(min(ys), max(ys)+1):
    print(''.join(matrix[(i, j)] if (i, j) in matrix else ' '
                  for i in range(min(xs), max(xs)+1)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! According to the rules outlined in [our help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), all solutions to challenges should be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. For example, an entry to a code golf contest needs to be golfed.

Comment: I'm added the byte count for you, but there's quite a lot of unnecessary spaces in there which you might want to remove.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made the necessary changes to my first entry. Any extra advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I [really golfed it](https://bpaste.net/show/664fef9533f5).

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ That just prints `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @Dennis Hrm... unusual behavior, try replacing `0,1` with `(0,1)` removing the space and see if that helps (HELP: Line number would be appreciated!)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>35</s> <s>34</s> <s>30</s> 28 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•₃º•"<>v^"©‡0ªÐUĀ>sŽO^®XkèΛ
```

Uses `0` as head of the snake.

-4 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDokdNzYd2AWklG7uyOKVDKx81LDQ4tOrwhNAjDXbFR/f6xx1aF5F9eMW52f//pwBBIhAUg0AKApSDAE4JMADLoCsBy4AYcCkUG2BKoUaAFcKtAamDGgkBCLOQRVGE4Y4AAA) (no test suite for all test cases at once, because there is no way to reset the Canvas, so outputs would overlap..).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•₃º•          # Push compressed string "adsw"
     "<>v^"    # Push string "<>v^"
           ©   # Save it in variable `r` (without popping)
            ‡  # Transliterate the (implicit) input-string,
               # replacing all "adsw" with "<>v^" respectively
               #  i.e. "ddddssaassdddddww" → ">>>>vv<<vv>>>>>^^"
0ª             # Convert the string to a list of characters, and append a 0 (for the head)
               #  → [">",">",">",">","v","v","<","<","v","v",">",">",">",">",">","^","^","0"]
  Ð            # Triplicate this list of characters
   U           # Pop and store one of the three lists in variable `X`
   Ā           # Trutify each character ("0" remains 0; everything else becomes 1)
    >          # And then increase each integer by 1
               #  → [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1]
  s            # Swap the two lists on the stack
      ®Xk      # Get the index of each character of variable `X` in variable `r` ("<>v^")
               #  i.e. [">",">",">",">","v","v","<","<","v","v",">",">",">",">",">","^","^","0"]
               #   → [1,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,-1]
   ŽO^   è     # And use those to index into the compressed number 6240
               #  → [2,2,2,2,4,4,6,6,4,4,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0]
Λ              # Use the Canvas builtin with these three lists
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•₃º•` is `"adsw"` and `ŽO^` is `6240`.

As for a brief explanation of the Canvas builtin `Λ` and its three arguments:

**First argument: length(s):** the sizes of the lines we want to draw. Since we have to keep in mind overlapping, we use size 2 for every character, and an additional 1 for the head of the snake.
**Second argument: string(s):** the characters we want to display. Which are the characters in this case, appended with the head-character of the snake.
**Third argument: direction(s):** the directions these character-lines of the given length should be drawn in. In general we have the directions `[0,7]` which map to these directions:

```python
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

Which is why we have the integer `6240` for the directions \$[←,→,↓,↑]\$ respectively.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for a more detailed explanation about the Canvas builtin `Λ`.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)

Comment: I might have missed something, but I don't think `γ` is needed at all. [This](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDokdNzYd2AWklG7uyOKVDKx81LDQ4tMol9Ehj0KPOBXbFR/f6xx1aF5F9eMW52f//pwBBIhAUg0AKApSDAE4JMADLoCsBy4AYcCkUG2BKoUaAFcKtAamDGgkBCLOQRVGE4Y4AAA) seem to work just fine.

Comment: @Grimy Thanks, it indeed does; nice alternative approach with the list of 2s and 1 for the head! And I've been able to save 2 more bytes based off your program.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently at [23](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLu56uEJhzu1leLs7MqUDu3SO9xweIXBoVUuRxrsis7N/v8/BQgSgaAYBFIQoBwEcEqAAVgGXQlYBsSAS6HYAFMKNQKsEG4NSB3USAhAmIUsiiIMdwQA), though that's a significantly different approach, so I might make it its own answer if that's fine by you.

Comment: @Grimy That indeed is quite a different approach than mine, so feel free to post it. I was indeed kinda expecting some unicode conversion and modulo might make this shorter than the transliterate, but I'm quite honestly pretty bad with those kind of magic integer/string conversions. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl - 394

Not the shortest, but it beats Javascript, C# and Java at least.

```
use List::Util qw(min max);sub c{()=$_[0]=~/$_[1]/g}%l=(a,['<',-1,0],d,['>',1,0],w,['^',0,-1],s=>['v',0,1]);($s,$x,$y,$w,$h)=($ARGV[0],0,0,max(c($s,a),c($s,d)),max(c($s,w),c($s,'s')));@s=split'',$s;map$x=min($x,$i+=$l{$_}[1]),@s;$i=0;map$y=min($y,$i+=$l{$_}[2]),@s;$x=abs $x;$y=abs $y;map{$m[$y][$x]=$l{$_}[0];$x+=$l{$_}[1];$y+=$l{$_}[2]}@s;$m[$y][$x]='o';map{map{print$_||' '}@$_;print"\n"}@m
```

Some tricks:

- Warnings and strict not turned on to allow barewords and not declaring variables before using them
- Thin commas instead of fat commas to save a few characters
- Not setting initial values for variables when not necessary
- Leaving out semi-colons when possible
- Defining arrays and hashes not as references to avoid having to use ->
- Allowing width, height to be larger than necessary to avoid having to calculate them accurately (which would take extra code)

Things that hurt:

- No built-in way to count number of characters in a string (might have been longer anyway)
- No built-in min/max functions, thus need to waste 27 characters to import library that does it (less than defining our own)

Answer (score 1):

## C - 273 bytes - with Interactive Input!

```
#define F for(i=w*w
*g,*G,x,i,j,w,W,u;main(w){putch(1);F;j=-~getch();g=G){if(!(x%w&&~-~x%w&&x/w&&x/w^~-w)){W=w+6;G=calloc(W*W,4);F-1;u=i%w+i/w*W-~W*3,i==x?x=u:8,i;)G[u]=g[i--];free(g);w=W;}G[x]="<^X>v"[j%=7];G[x+=1-G[x]%3+W*(!!j-j/2)]=1;F;i;)putch(i--%W?G[i]?G[i]:32:10);}}
```

The field is printed each time a character is entered and grows if the snake's head nears the edge. I don't know how portable it is--someone on the Internet said getch() doesn't work on non-Windows platforms. Hard to say whether ASCII 1 will look like a smiley face either.

The golfed version is quite annoying as there is no way to gracefully exit the program. Control-C doesn't work for me. On the other hand, the ungolfed version terminates if a character other than 'w', 'a', 's', or 'd' is entered.

So-called "ungolfed":

```
#define SMILEYFACE 1
int main()
{
    int o;
    int w = 1;
    int *g = 0, *g2;
    int c, n;
    int x = 0;
    for( putch(SMILEYFACE);c = getch(); ) {
        if(c!='w'&&c!='a'&&c!='s'&&c!='d')
            return 1;
        if(!(x%w) | !(~-~x%w) | !(x/w)  | !(x/w-~-w) ) {
            int wnew = w + 4;
            int off = 2;
            g2 = calloc(wnew*wnew,sizeof(int));
            for(n = w*w; --n; )
                g2[ n%w+off + (n/w+off)*wnew ] = g[n];
            free(g);
            g = g2;
            x = (x/w+off)*wnew + x%w + off;
            w = wnew;
        }
        int i = -~c%7;
        g[x] = "<^X>v"[i];
        int dx = 1-g[x]%3 + w * (!!i-i/2);
        x += dx;
        g[x] = SMILEYFACE;
        for(o = w*w; o; )
            putch(o--%w?g[o]?g[o]:32:10);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

```
Ç7%DÉ+D"^>>v"ºsè0ªDĀ>rΛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLu5qsvhTm0XpTg7uzKlQ7uKD68wOLTK5UiDXdG52f//pwBBIhAUg0AKApSDAE4JMADLoCsBy4AYcCkUG2BKoUaAFcKtAamDGgkBCLOQRVGE4Y4AAA)

Explanation:

```
                      # implicit input (eg: "wasd")
Ç                     # codepoints (eg: [119, 97, 115, 100])
 7%                   # modulo 7 (eg: [0, 6, 3, 2])
   DÉ+                # plus itself modulo 2 (eg: [0, 6, 4, 2])
# This is the list of directions that will be passed to 05AB1E's canvas function, Λ.
# 0 means up, 6 left, 4 right, 2 down.

 "^>>v"º              # "^>>v", horizontally mirrored (namely "^>>vv<<^")
D       sè            # index into this with a copy of the list of directions
          0ª          # append "0"
# This is the list of strings that will be drawn.

D                     # duplicate the list of strings
 Ā                    # truthify (maps letters to 1, 0 stays 0)
  >                   # increment each
# This is the list of lengths to draw.

r                     # reverse the stack because Λ takes arguments in the opposite order
 Λ                    # draw!
```